# unable to run example of OpenCV in beagleBone Black

Tags: c++, opencv, beagleboneblack

I am trying to run a program using OpenCV in beaglebone black as described at the end of the link https://solarianprogrammer.com/2014/04/21/opencv-beaglebone-black-ubuntu/

I had some compilation issues which I resolved using

g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` test_2.cpp -o test_2

It successfully compiles, but when I try to run using

./test_2

I get the error:

```
Ipc_start: LAD_connect() failed: 4
test_2: /build/ti-opencl-zdvBAC/ti-opencl-01.01.06.00/host/src/core/dsp/mbox_impl_msgq.cpp:59: MBoxMsgQ::MBoxMsgQ(Coal::DSPDevice*): Assertion `status == (0) || status == (1)' failed.
Aborted
```

I am not sure why I am getting this, and I've been unable to resolve it for a few days already. Please guide me into right direction.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stems from the use of OpenCL under the covers. The bypass that works for me is to disable opencl by setting:
`export OPENCV_OPENCL_RUNTIME=qqq`

Optionally, if you're (cross) compiling OpenCV you can add `-DWITH_OPENCL=OFF` to your Cmake options to remove OpenCL from the build.